# How to change the frame colors with OpenCV to be same as display?

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

I'm unable to change the colors so that they are the same as my natural diaply colors. They are always inverted. I have tried using different color spaces, but am not able to have it work. I want the program to capture my screen, but also be able detect certain colors on the screen

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui


def nothing(x):
    pass


cv2.namedWindow("Tracking")
cv2.createTrackbar("LH", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("LS", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("LV", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UH", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("US", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UV", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)

while True:

    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot = np.array(screenshot)

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #

    l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LH", "Tracking")
    l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LS", "Tracking")
    l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LV", "Tracking")

    u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("UH", "Tracking")
    u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("US", "Tracking")
    u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("UV", "Tracking")

    l_b = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
    u_b = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, l_b, u_b)

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(screenshot, screenshot, mask=mask)

    # cv2.imshow("screenshot", screenshot)
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("res", res)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking screenshot using Pyautogui which must be reading it in RGB instead of the BGR used in Opencv. So after reading the screenshot convert it to BGR.

```
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot = np.array(screenshot)
screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```